# Tree Traversal, the output is wrong

Tags: java, c++, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to solve this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber-iii/

> The thief has found himself a new place for his thievery again. There is only one entrance to this area, called the "root." Besides the root, each house has one and only one parent house. After a tour, the smart thief realized that "all houses in this place forms a binary tree". It will automatically contact the police if two directly-linked houses were broken into on the same night.

Now with this input:

> Input: [4,1,null,2,null,3]

That should be this tree:[image]

Now in my opinion the correct output is `4+2 = 6` but leetcode says the correct is 7.

Did I draw wrong the tree? How can you obtain a max 7 rob given that tree?

Comment: It's not clear what ordering of the tree that list is, but I believe 1 and 2 have right children, not left

Answer (score 1):

Number 4 and 3 are also not connected, so 4+3 would also count and would be higher than 4 + 2. It is about nodes that are connected. As long as they are not directly connected, the thief can rob them, thus 4+3 could be robbed.

Answer (score 1):

What's stopping you from robbing 4 + 3 = 7? Those two "houses" are not directly linked.

Comment: that's right, I thought you couldn't do a double jump